# sync records in bulk using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, bulkupdate

In this scenario I have two tables **Table A** and **Table B**
Now get all records from the **Table A** which have a label "Updated" and "synced" = 0.

Now I loop through each record and update the records in Table B,and changed the synced column in Table A = 1.But this process takes hours and sometimes MySQL return Failed to response data 
I have shared the code

```
$RecordTableA = 100000rows <br>
foreach ($RecordTableA as $val) { <br>
   $commands = Update Table B SET allcolumnB WHERE bla blaa;<br>
   $commands->execute();<br>
}<br>
$cmd = Update Table A SET synced = 0 WHERE label = updated;<br>
$cmd->execute();<br>
```

Comment: MySQL has a [multiple table UPDATE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html). Don't run SQL in a loop, its better at doing it that you. If its a lot of rows, ensure your innodb buffer pool size is set large enough (up to 80% ram). Be specific about the code and where the RecordTablA comes from.

Comment: RecordTableA comes from another database and I also set the buffer pool size up to 80% ram If I don't run SQL in a loop then how can I set values in bulk.

Comment: *RecordTableA comes from another database* it doesn't matter. Is it the same MySQL instance?

Comment: No two Instances 
clientDB_is_a_instance_of_RecordTableA
myDB_is_a_instance_of_RecordTableB

Comment: Why not update in one go. 
`UPDATE tableB
INNER JOIN tableA ON tableB.name = tableA.name
SET tableB.col1 =  tableA.col1 , tableB.col2 =  tableA.col2 , .......
WHERE blah blah .......   
;`

Comment: you can even extend to cross database references in the same query `UPDATE myDB.TableB INNER JOIN  clientDB.TableA...`

Comment: how can I execute cross database query i-e 
$clientDB->createquery()
$myDB->createquery()

Comment: A single mysql instance support multiple databases. Your answer on two instances isn't particularly clear on if they are in the same database server. Please clarify this first.